# Python FuzzyWuzzy ratio: how does it work?

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy

Inside the FuzzyWuzzy ratio description it says:

The FuzzyWuzzy ratio raw score is a measure of the strings similarity as an int in the range [0, 100]. For two strings X and Y, the score is defined by int(round((2.0 * M / T) * 100)) where T is the total number of characters in both strings, and M is the number of matches in the two strings. The FuzzyWuzzy ratio sim score is a float in the range [0, 1] and is obtained by dividing the raw score by 100.

Then how come this score appears to be different when I change the order of the words?

```
 from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

 fuzz.ratio('EMRE MERT', 'OMER CAN') / 100 = 0.35

 fuzz.ratio('EMRE MERT', 'CAN OMER') / 100 = 0.47
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition you're using comes from the [Ratio](https://anhaidgroup.github.io/py_stringmatching/v0.3.x/Ratio.html) function in the `py_stringmatching` module, but the function you're using is from the [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) module which uses the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

From the [recursive implementation of Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Recursive) you can see that the algorithm considers the strings character-by-character, and so changing the order of the characters will change the output value.